# Using JQuery Variable within Razor

Tags: jquery, razor

How do you make use of a jquery variable within `Url.Action` within jquery?

```
var id = "10";
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id })';
```

Thanks

Comment: The question is, does your id need to be set client side? Or can that value of "10" also be set server-side using Razor (e.g. like `var id = "@(myServerValue)"` and `@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { Id = myServerValue })`)

Answer (score 3):

try, replace function by placing a token:

```
var id = "10";
var actionUrl = "@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController", new { Id= "TabId" })";
window.location.href = actionUrl.replace("TabId", id);
```

Comment: +1: Token replacement is a good workaround if the value needs to come from client-side. This allows for more complex URLs than simply appending the parameter to the URL.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie What if you don't want to send any value, i.e. you have a nullable field. This approach won't work, the best you can do is send an empty string, e.g. Id=1&SomeNullableField=&SomeOtherField=2

Comment: @Rui: that seems unlikely in this example, but a `regex` replace like `/[?&]Id=TabId/` etc instead would do that (if you want nulls). The problem with your example below is that it does handle other parameters (which happen frequently in using `Action`). You then need to handle `?` and `&` cases.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Handling ? and & is not really an issue if you use jQuery, for example `$.param({id: 10, someOtherParameter:20})` -> id=10&someOtherParameter=20

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I've changed my answer to reflect this

Comment: @Rui: Then you should put all these ideas in your own answer (which you just did), instead of criticising Zaheer Ahmed about features *his will probably not need for the simple question asked*. I just happen to avoid string concatenation generally :)

Comment: @Rui replacing with empty string will handle null situation.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed A simple experiment will disprove that. If your parameter is a string and you pass param= in the query string you'll get an empty string, if you omit the parameter altogether it will be null.

Comment: @Rui in this particular question, OP is passing id, and I think Id cant be null, if that is there are many ways like passing zero or negative nos and considering it as null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a jQuery variable in Razor.
The reason why you can't use a javascript variable in razor is that razor runs in the server. Javascript runs in the client.

You could however store that url in a javascript variable and then use it to build the specific url you need, i.e.:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';

window.location.href = url + "?id=" + id;
```

If you need to pass several parameters and you don't want to handle creating a string with ?param1=X&param2=Y etc you can use jQuery's param method, i.e.:

```
window.location.href = url + "?" + $.param({id:10, param2:"hello"});
```

`$.param({id:10, param2:"hello"})` returns id=10&param2=hello

Comment: The only reason I prefer the token replacement answer is I personally hate the maintenance problems caused by string concatenation in code. Also, the question asked was a very simple example, so only needed a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly..
To achieve this I would make an Ajax call with your jQuery to a Razor page passing your jQuery parameters as GET/POST then retrieve the GET/POST on the Razor page and pass something back via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery,javascript statements and variables are evaluated in browser. Razor is evaluated in web server. So you cannot do what you mean. But if you set value in a razor variable, you can use it on both razor and javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the set of possible answers, *if* your variable value is known server-side (you have not clarified that point) you can also inject Razor values into your javascript:

### e.g.

```
var id = "@(myServerValue)";
window.location.href = @Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { Id = myServerValue }))
```

If the value is only known client-side, you can use a client-side replace as Zaheer Ahmed and Rui suggested.

If you need to handle null cases, and want to remove the extra param, I would go as far as using a regex to match the replacement: