# Serializing a List<T> in C# and deserializing it into js array

Tags: javascript, json, razor, json.net

<s>I have a razor part in my javascript but can't access the js-variable that has been put in as a parameter to the js-function.</s>

I am trying to serialize a List and then deserialize the json string into a js-array.

```
<script>
function listContainerBlobs(json, container) {
    @*var arr = @JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);*@
    var arr = JSON.parse(json);
    var blobs = document.getElementById('container-blob-display').innerHTML = "<h4>" + container + "</h4>";
    var otherDiv = document.getElementById('section-1');
    var thisDiv = document.getElementById('section-2');

    otherDiv.style.display = 'none';
    thisDiv.style.display = 'block';

    var blobNumber = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        blobNumber++;
        var blobId = "blobId" + blobNumber;
        blobs += "<p class='search-result' id='" + blobId + "' onclick='downloadBlob('" + blobId + "', '" + arr[i].Name + "', '" + container + "')' style='float: left; '>" + arr[i].Name + "</p>";
    }
}</script>
```

This is the C# code in the razor page which serializes the List returned by a method. I am wondering if the formats of the json strings are different and therefore I cannot deserialize the json string within js.

```
var blobs = await Model.ListContainerBlobs(container.Name);
var jsonBlob = Json.Serialize(blobs);
//var jsonBlob = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobs);
```

I use `blobs` in a few lopps and stuff in the html-page but thought I'd reuse this methodcall for the parameter in the js-function `listContainerBlobs(json, container)` therefore the json serialization.

Js-function call:

```
<p class="search-result blob-container" id="@containerId" onclick="listContainerBlobs('@jsonBlob','@containerModel.Name')">@containerModel.Name</p>
```

Error received when debugging in the browser:
[image]

<s>By reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626958/using-jquery-variable-within-razor), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957996/using-a-javascript-variable-within-razor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815919/razor-variable-used-within-more-razor-within-javascript) I guess I have to just accept that I can't call a js-variable inside razor.</s>

Does anyone have a workaround on this or maybe a better solution to the serializing/deserializing of this c# list?

If important here are the different json types I serialize into

- Json.Serialize(blobs); :

> "[{\"StreamWriteSizeInBytes\":4194304,\"ServiceClient\":{\"BufferManager\":null,\"Credentials\":{\"SASToken\":null,\"AccountName\":\"devstoreaccount1\",\"KeyName\":null,\"IsAnonymous\":false,\"IsSAS\":false,\"IsSharedKey\":true,\"IsToken\":false,\"SASSignature\":null},\"BaseUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary\"},\"DefaultRequestOptions\":{\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry\":null,\"LocationMode\":0,\"ServerTimeout\":null,\"MaximumExecutionTime\":null,\"ParallelOperationThreadCount\":1,\"SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes\":134217728,\"UseTransactionalMD5\":null,\"StoreBlobContentMD5\":null,\"DisableContentMD5Validation\":null},\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"DefaultDelimiter\":\"/\",\"AuthenticationScheme\":1},\"StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes\":4194304,\"Properties\":{\"CacheControl\":null,\"ContentDisposition\":null,\"ContentEncoding\":null,\"ContentLanguage\":null,\"Length\":68,\"ContentMD5\":\"YUP3oQ5rwX9qEtwa7Op0Iw==\",\"ContentType\":\"text/plain\",\"ETag\":\"\\"0x8D757BD9E066830\\"\",\"Created\":\"2019-10-22T09:06:29+00:00\",\"LastModified\":\"2019-10-23T13:33:40+00:00\",\"BlobType\":2,\"LeaseStatus\":2,\"LeaseState\":1,\"LeaseDuration\":0,\"PageBlobSequenceNumber\":null,\"AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount\":null,\"IsServerEncrypted\":true,\"IsIncrementalCopy\":false,\"StandardBlobTier\":0,\"RehydrationStatus\":null,\"PremiumPageBlobTier\":null,\"BlobTierInferred\":false,\"BlobTierLastModifiedTime\":null,\"DeletedTime\":null,\"RemainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete\":null},\"Metadata\":{},\"Uri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\"},\"SnapshotTime\":null,\"IsSnapshot\":false,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"SnapshotQualifiedUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\",\"SnapshotQualifiedStorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container/FirstBlob.txt\"},\"CopyState\":null,\"Name\":\"FirstBlob.txt\",\"Container\":{\"ServiceClient\":{\"BufferManager\":null,\"Credentials\":{\"SASToken\":null,\"AccountName\":\"devstoreaccount1\",\"KeyName\":null,\"IsAnonymous\":false,\"IsSAS\":false,\"IsSharedKey\":true,\"IsToken\":false,\"SASSignature\":null},\"BaseUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary\"},\"DefaultRequestOptions\":{\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry\":null,\"LocationMode\":0,\"ServerTimeout\":null,\"MaximumExecutionTime\":null,\"ParallelOperationThreadCount\":1,\"SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes\":134217728,\"UseTransactionalMD5\":null,\"StoreBlobContentMD5\":null,\"DisableContentMD5Validation\":null},\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"DefaultDelimiter\":\"/\",\"AuthenticationScheme\":1},\"Uri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container\"},\"Name\":\"first-container\",\"Metadata\":{},\"Properties\":{\"ETag\":null,\"HasImmutabilityPolicy\":null,\"HasLegalHold\":null,\"LastModified\":null,\"LeaseStatus\":0,\"LeaseState\":0,\"LeaseDuration\":0,\"PublicAccess\":null}},\"Parent\":{\"ServiceClient\":{\"BufferManager\":null,\"Credentials\":{\"SASToken\":null,\"AccountName\":\"devstoreaccount1\",\"KeyName\":null,\"IsAnonymous\":false,\"IsSAS\":false,\"IsSharedKey\":true,\"IsToken\":false,\"SASSignature\":null},\"BaseUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary\"},\"DefaultRequestOptions\":{\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry\":null,\"LocationMode\":0,\"ServerTimeout\":null,\"MaximumExecutionTime\":null,\"ParallelOperationThreadCount\":1,\"SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes\":134217728,\"UseTransactionalMD5\":null,\"StoreBlobContentMD5\":null,\"DisableContentMD5Validation\":null},\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"DefaultDelimiter\":\"/\",\"AuthenticationScheme\":1},\"Uri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container\"},\"Container\":{\"ServiceClient\":{\"BufferManager\":null,\"Credentials\":{\"SASToken\":null,\"AccountName\":\"devstoreaccount1\",\"KeyName\":null,\"IsAnonymous\":false,\"IsSAS\":false,\"IsSharedKey\":true,\"IsToken\":false,\"SASSignature\":null},\"BaseUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary\"},\"DefaultRequestOptions\":{\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry\":null,\"LocationMode\":0,\"ServerTimeout\":null,\"MaximumExecutionTime\":null,\"ParallelOperationThreadCount\":1,\"SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes\":134217728,\"UseTransactionalMD5\":null,\"StoreBlobContentMD5\":null,\"DisableContentMD5Validation\":null},\"RetryPolicy\":{},\"DefaultDelimiter\":\"/\",\"AuthenticationScheme\":1},\"Uri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"StorageUri\":{\"PrimaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container\",\"SecondaryUri\":\"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container\"},\"Name\":\"first-container\",\"Metadata\":{},\"Properties\":{\"ETag\":null,\"HasImmutabilityPolicy\":null,\"HasLegalHold\":null,\"LastModified\":null,\"LeaseStatus\":0,\"LeaseState\":0,\"LeaseDuration\":0,\"PublicAccess\":null}},\"Parent\":null,\"Prefix\":\"\"},\"BlobType\":2}]"

- Jsonconvert.SerializeObject(blobs); :

> {[{"streamWriteSizeInBytes":4194304,"serviceClient":{"bufferManager":null,"credentials":{"sasToken":null,"accountName":"devstoreaccount1","keyName":null,"isAnonymous":false,"isSAS":false,"isSharedKey":true,"isToken":false,"sasSignature":null},"baseUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary"},"defaultRequestOptions":{"retryPolicy":{},"absorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry":null,"locationMode":0,"serverTimeout":null,"maximumExecutionTime":null,"parallelOperationThreadCount":1,"singleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes":134217728,"useTransactionalMD5":null,"storeBlobContentMD5":null,"disableContentMD5Validation":null},"retryPolicy":{},"defaultDelimiter":"/","authenticationScheme":1},"streamMinimumReadSizeInBytes":4194304,"properties":{"cacheControl":null,"contentDisposition":null,"contentEncoding":null,"contentLanguage":null,"length":68,"contentMD5":"YUP3oQ5rwX9qEtwa7Op0Iw==","contentType":"text/plain","eTag":"\u00220x8D757BD9E066830\u0022","created":"2019-10-22T09:06:29+00:00","lastModified":"2019-10-23T13:33:40+00:00","blobType":2,"leaseStatus":2,"leaseState":1,"leaseDuration":0,"pageBlobSequenceNumber":null,"appendBlobCommittedBlockCount":null,"isServerEncrypted":true,"isIncrementalCopy":false,"standardBlobTier":0,"rehydrationStatus":null,"premiumPageBlobTier":null,"blobTierInferred":false,"blobTierLastModifiedTime":null,"deletedTime":null,"remainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete":null},"metadata":{},"uri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container/FirstBlob.txt"},"snapshotTime":null,"isSnapshot":false,"isDeleted":false,"snapshotQualifiedUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt","snapshotQualifiedStorageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container/FirstBlob.txt","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container/FirstBlob.txt"},"copyState":null,"name":"FirstBlob.txt","container":{"serviceClient":{"bufferManager":null,"credentials":{"sasToken":null,"accountName":"devstoreaccount1","keyName":null,"isAnonymous":false,"isSAS":false,"isSharedKey":true,"isToken":false,"sasSignature":null},"baseUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary"},"defaultRequestOptions":{"retryPolicy":{},"absorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry":null,"locationMode":0,"serverTimeout":null,"maximumExecutionTime":null,"parallelOperationThreadCount":1,"singleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes":134217728,"useTransactionalMD5":null,"storeBlobContentMD5":null,"disableContentMD5Validation":null},"retryPolicy":{},"defaultDelimiter":"/","authenticationScheme":1},"uri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container"},"name":"first-container","metadata":{},"properties":{"eTag":null,"hasImmutabilityPolicy":null,"hasLegalHold":null,"lastModified":null,"leaseStatus":0,"leaseState":0,"leaseDuration":0,"publicAccess":null}},"parent":{"serviceClient":{"bufferManager":null,"credentials":{"sasToken":null,"accountName":"devstoreaccount1","keyName":null,"isAnonymous":false,"isSAS":false,"isSharedKey":true,"isToken":false,"sasSignature":null},"baseUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary"},"defaultRequestOptions":{"retryPolicy":{},"absorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry":null,"locationMode":0,"serverTimeout":null,"maximumExecutionTime":null,"parallelOperationThreadCount":1,"singleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes":134217728,"useTransactionalMD5":null,"storeBlobContentMD5":null,"disableContentMD5Validation":null},"retryPolicy":{},"defaultDelimiter":"/","authenticationScheme":1},"uri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container"},"container":{"serviceClient":{"bufferManager":null,"credentials":{"sasToken":null,"accountName":"devstoreaccount1","keyName":null,"isAnonymous":false,"isSAS":false,"isSharedKey":true,"isToken":false,"sasSignature":null},"baseUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary"},"defaultRequestOptions":{"retryPolicy":{},"absorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry":null,"locationMode":0,"serverTimeout":null,"maximumExecutionTime":null,"parallelOperationThreadCount":1,"singleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes":134217728,"useTransactionalMD5":null,"storeBlobContentMD5":null,"disableContentMD5Validation":null},"retryPolicy":{},"defaultDelimiter":"/","authenticationScheme":1},"uri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","storageUri":{"primaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/first-container","secondaryUri":"http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1-secondary/first-container"},"name":"first-container","metadata":{},"properties":{"eTag":null,"hasImmutabilityPolicy":null,"hasLegalHold":null,"lastModified":null,"leaseStatus":0,"leaseState":0,"leaseDuration":0,"publicAccess":null}},"parent":null,"prefix":""},"blobType":2}]}

To recreate this, serialize a List by C#, send the json string through onclick="" to your js-function and deserialize the string inside the function.

Comment: Why can't you replace `@JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)` with `JSON.parse(json)` in your `listContainerBlobs` function?   `JSON.parse` (note, lowercase `p` in `parse`) works just fine with arrays.  If it doesn't work for you for some reason, can you please post a [mre] in your question so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @BrianRogers JSON.parse would be awesome (then I don't have to use raor inside javascript). I get an error though and I am wondering if that is because the json string format is different for the json.parse and Json.Serialize (also tried JsonConvert.SerializeObject, but none of them seem to work). I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a workaround by creating a object of my own containing the values that I wanted/needed.

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();

objects.Add(new
    {
        blobCount = blobs.Count,
        blobs = blobs.Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Container = x.Container,
            Blobtype = x.BlobType,
            Uri = x.Uri
         })
     });

var jsonBlob = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobObject);
```

I noticed that the result of deserializing the json-string was faulty. One part of the string wasn't deserialized correctly (according to my human eyes and mind but probably correctly according to the json format). I didn't need this property anyway so this works perfectly in my case.

Hopefully this might help *someone* else...

Also according to [this link](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) (which checks if the format of your json-string is valid) the Json.Serialize(i) was correct but became faulty inside the browser, and the JsonConverter.SerializeObject(i) was invalid. Though after making a new list of objects the later was the one which was wokring and not the first one.